# Android binding library Failed resolution of: L....../R$layout

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to create Xamarin support for my Android SDK (So potential clients can implement it as Xamarin Android app.

I was trying to avoid using AAR because I wanted  resources  to be available to the client, so the client can customize the layout. In android library it is usually very easy because one can create JAR file only from the java classes and leave the res folder as is with all the resources available for editing.
I was trying to do the Same with xamarin studio: I located the jar under jars and also added .so files under lib/jni. Then I copied the res folder content to Resources.
The result was:
In the Xamarin app (that uses the dll from the binding project) I could see the Resources. But! When I am running the java classes (I use those resources in the SDK code) I get an error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: L....../R$layout.
I didn't find any documentation on using resources outside the jar...

Is there another option maybe with Android resources that are defined inside AAR, to  override them outside the AAR.

Thanks in advance for any answer/reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only main difference between a JAR and AAR is that AARs can include resources. If a client needs to customize the resources, you have a couple of ways.

1. A Xamarin.Android Class Library that can be customized, recompiled, and added to a project.
2. An Android Class Library that can be customized then packaged into an AAR to be bound by a binding project.

Finally you could always just instruct your clients to purposely override your library's resources as the application resource will be prioritized rather than the library.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#resource_merging

Comment: Thanks @Jon Douglas. I chose the "third" option ("Finally..."), override most of the resources to the Xamarin App, and now the elements can be customized.